# How to calculate the angle between Quaternions

Tags: python, ros, sensors, robotics, imu

I have two IMU sensors giving me Euler angles. I convert them to Quaternion by following

```
quaternion_angle_1=tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll_1,pitch_1,yaw_1)
quaternion_angle_2=tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll_2,pitch_2,yaw_2)
```

Now I want to caculate the angle between these measurements from the IMU sensors. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain the angle between two quaternions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063595/how-to-obtain-the-angle-between-two-quaternions)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the relative rotation between two quaternions. You could simple calculate the angle between the euler angles, then convert that to a quaternion. But if you need to do it strictly with quaternions `tf` allows you to do this directly:

```
relative_quat = quaternion_angle_1 * quaternion_angle_2.inverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

An amazing python library for all quaternion/euler/matrix conversions and operations is [transforms3d](https://matthew-brett.github.io/transforms3d/). To got from quaternion a, to quaternion b, you could just do -

```
quat_c = tf3.quaternions.qmult(quat_b, tf3.quaternions.qconjugate(quat_a))
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ggupta9777/eefdc98b9749caf9b972a7fcad620839#file-quat_difference-py)  is a github gist for the above example.

Or if you are using [tf/transformations.py](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/noetic-devel/tf/src/tf/transformations.py),

```
quat_c = quaternion_multiply(quat_b, quaternion_conjugate(quat_a))
```

Quaternion multiplication involves taking a [hamiltonian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product), therefore simply taking the dot/cross/element-wise multiplication of two quaternions will not be enough.